# In org babel, how to get results from an output file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying write a org babel for SAS. And it is known that SAS can only generate a 'XXX.lst' from source 'XXX.sas' if the output lst file is not specified. Now I meet the problem to get the file content of 'XXX.lst' to the corresponding results '#+RESULTS:'. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org mode will try to call your org-babel-execute:sas function. If you are working with SAS via ESS, the best way to implement execution of SAS source code blocks in Org model is to mimic the integration with R (in ob-R.el) and connect Org to the ESS SAS session. The user's documentation is [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html).

Or you can just call SAS in your org-babel-execute:sas and substitute the output file like this:

```
(with-temp-buffer (insert-file-contents your-sas-output-file) (buffer-string))
```